# Powershell's colors, messing with Vim + Solarized theme

Tags: powershell, vim

Recently coming back from working on unix systems to Windows 7, I am trying to set up my Vim work environment from the basics up.

First off I wanted my favorite coloscheme, [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) to work with Powershell as it is the one that suited me best from all terminal type software on windows that I have tried.

My problem is that it seems the colors on Powershell do not quite go together, as you can see here: [CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdcOr.png) and [Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVum7.png) , with Vim + Solarized theme as they do on the normal Command Prompt even though I believe my colors on both have been set up the same.

I have attempted to include:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

inside of my _vimrc file as advised on the Solarized site, but it made it even [worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47W3.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be way off, and I assume you've probably already looked into this, but you may have to configure your user PowerShell profile to set the colours there as well.

Have a gander at the [MSDN docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx). But basically, you test for a profile first:

```
Test-Path $Profile
```

If false, create it:

```
New-Item –Type File –Force $Profile
```

It'll be stored in %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Then you can go about setting the default colours as detailed here:

[MSDN PowerShell colours](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692799.aspx)

I've never used VIM with PowerShell before though, never had any colour issues with ConEmu or Console2.

Comment: Yeah I did attempt this however it also didn't work, but thanks anyway, at this point I've given up on trying to get my Vim work with solarized in Powershell and just use it in Command Prompt. Funny thing though you mention that Console2 worked fine for you but Console2 does the same thing that powershell did when I use the Solarized theme :<

Comment: I'd suggest maybe trying out ConEmu, it's basically a console emulation layer, and whilst it's a bit of a pain to set up (a lot of options), it may help with your problem - here's two screenshots of it running
vim and PowerShell side by side, with a custom vim theme and some Solarized (it has several Solarized-derived themes built in!) theme for console itself used on the PowerShell instance.

http://imgur.com/bnisEC0,ufIdrdp#0

Comment: AH ConEmu actually solves it for me :D Everything works great, thanks!